# Flutter - How to change a variable in custom class widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this very simple `Test.dart` custom class widget and I want to be able to change the value of the variable `color` inside the `main.drat` and update it

```
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  var color;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          color: color,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the value to color in constructor of Widget:

```dart
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  final Color color;
  Test(this.color);

  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          color: widget.color,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Then you can call this `Test` Widget like this:

```
Test(myColor);
```

Flutter is optimized for rebuilding Widgets, so you don't need to set color separately, you can simply rebuild the Widget with the new value.

Comment: I am getting an error : `error: The instance member 'widget' can't be accessed in an initializer.`@Tuqay